# Fatal Error while setting up site on local

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I have **Drupal 7** Site. I am setting up a remote site on my local.

While setting up the site, getting the following error from Apache

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp\www\mySite\mySite-website\usr\share\drupal7/sites/all/modules/isotope/plugins/export_ui/isotope_ctools_export_ui.inc'
>   (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\PEAR') in
>   C:\wamp\www\mySite\mySite-website\usr\share\drupal7\sites\all\modules\ctools\includes\plugins.inc
>   on line 477-

I am definitely not an expert of Apache. I also tried navigating to a test.html page I placed in common/configs/ so I assume there are no rights issues going on.

PEAR is successfully installed.

Not sure what to do at this point

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Give require permission to directories. And check .htaccess also.

Comment: @SanjayChaudhari. already provided..

Comment: Is your remote server a WAMP server?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII.. Not sure about that..But in local yes

Comment: Well you're trying to require a file based on a Windows filesystem `C:\wamp` looks like it's leftover from your home development. You might need to change the hard coded include path

Comment: @JeffPuckettII.. nopes still issue persists